# Trigger throws error while trying to insert into another db on insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, digital-ocean

I am trying to insert into 'latestdb' from 'fold' database on the same server under localhost, throws this error:

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE trigger after_insert_db1_t1 AFTER INSERT ON  `fold`.pr_users
FOR each
ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO  `latestdb`.pr_users(

username,
userpass,
email
)
VALUES (
NEW.username, NEW.userpass, NEW.email
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '' at line 1

Both the tables have the same name, with these fields -

`id`, `username`, `userpass`, `email`, `departmentid`, `userroleid`, `managerid`, `userlevel`, `branchid`, `is_global`, `registrationtime`, `timemodified`, `modifierid`, `status`, `deleted`, `temppass`, `temppassvalidtill`, `lastlogin`, `lastrefresh`, `lastloginip`, `if_online`, `pfield`, `company`

But i want to only copy 3 fields - username,userpass, email

Comment: The assumption would be that `id` is an auto-generated field, and that all fields apart from `id`, `username`, `userpass` and `email` are `nullable`.

Comment: yes , absolutely right @PeterAbolins

Comment: If you look at the error, you will note it says it is a **syntax** error.
You are missing an `END;`. cf: https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/triggers/after_insert.php

Comment: NEW.username, NEW.userpass, NEW.email
)
END; but still getting error @PeterAbolins checked   );END; Also but got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `BEGIN` and `END;` seems to remove the syntax error issue here.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_db1_t1 
    AFTER INSERT ON `fold`.pr_users 
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO `latestdb`.pr_users(
       username, userpass, email
    )
    VALUES (
       NEW.username, NEW.userpass, NEW.email
    );
```

Comment: Thank u @PeterAbolins

Comment: @sunshine You are welcome, although it seems somewhat uncomfortable that compound statements are not allowed. To be fair, I have found other posts where people have the same issue with MariaDB, but no explanations.